# How to shorten the SQL query using for loop?

Tags: python, sql

This is my current code:

```
def writeFile(fileName, tableName):
    sig = sd.SignalData("../raw_data/" + fileName)
    sql_file = tableName + ".sql"
    f = open(sql_file, "w")
    f.write(createTable)
    lines = []
    for i in range(len(sig.IMU.Lshank.time)):
        lshank_accel_x = sig.IMU.Lshank.a[i][0]
        lshank_accel_y = sig.IMU.Lshank.a[i][1]
        lshank_accel_z = sig.IMU.Lshank.a[i][2]
        lshank_gyro_x = sig.IMU.Lshank.w[i][0]
        lshank_gyro_y = sig.IMU.Lshank.w[i][1]
        lshank_gyro_z = sig.IMU.Lshank.w[i][2]
        lshank_mag_x = sig.IMU.Lshank.m[i][0]
        lshank_mag_y = sig.IMU.Lshank.m[i][1]
        lshank_mag_z = sig.IMU.Lshank.m[i][2]
        insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {tableName} (lshank_time,lshank_accel_x, lshank_accel_y, lshank_accel_z,lshank_gyro_x, lshank_gyro_y, lshank_gyro_z,lshank_mag_x, lshank_mag_y, lshank_mag_z) VALUES ({sig.IMU.Lshank.time[i]}, {lshank_accel_x}, {lshank_accel_y}, {lshank_accel_z}, {lshank_gyro_x}, {lshank_gyro_y}, {lshank_gyro_z}, {lshank_mag_x}, {lshank_mag_y}, {lshank_mag_z});\n"
        lines.append(insert_query)

    for i in range(len(sig.IMU.Rshank.time)):
        rshank_accel_x = sig.IMU.Rshank.a[i][0]
        rshank_accel_y = sig.IMU.Rshank.a[i][1]
        rshank_accel_z = sig.IMU.Rshank.a[i][2]
        rshank_gyro_x = sig.IMU.Rshank.w[i][0]
        rshank_gyro_y = sig.IMU.Rshank.w[i][1]
        rshank_gyro_z = sig.IMU.Rshank.w[i][2]
        rshank_mag_x = sig.IMU.Rshank.m[i][0]
        rshank_mag_y = sig.IMU.Rshank.m[i][1]
        rshank_mag_z = sig.IMU.Rshank.m[i][2]
        insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {tableName} (rshank_time,rshank_accel_x,rshank_accel_y,rshank_accel_z,rshank_gyro_x,rshank_gyro_y,rshank_gyro_z,rshank_mag_x,rshank_mag_y,rshank_mag_z) VALUES ({sig.IMU.Rshank.time[i]},{rshank_accel_x}, {rshank_accel_y}, {rshank_accel_z},{rshank_gyro_x},{rshank_gyro_y},{rshank_gyro_z},{rshank_mag_x},{rshank_mag_y},{rshank_mag_z});\n"
        lines.append(insert_query)
```

my instructor said the insert statement is too long, and he asked me to shorten the insert query using the pseudocode he provided me (in the screenshot). So how do I modify my code?
[pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seAnW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I think It will Work
Your First Insert Query's short form will be like this

```
insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {tableName} VALUES ({sig.IMU.Lshank.time[i]}, {lshank_accel_x}, {lshank_accel_y}, {lshank_accel_z}, {lshank_gyro_x}, {lshank_gyro_y}, {lshank_gyro_z}, {lshank_mag_x}, {lshank_mag_y}, {lshank_mag_z});\n"
```

Your Second Insert Query's short form will be like this

```
insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {tableName} VALUES ({sig.IMU.Rshank.time[i]},{rshank_accel_x}, {rshank_accel_y}, {rshank_accel_z},{rshank_gyro_x},{rshank_gyro_y},{rshank_gyro_z},{rshank_mag_x},{rshank_mag_y},{rshank_mag_z});\n"
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! But in this case, the sql query doesn't contain any variable names when I insert.

Comment: So is there another way to improve it?